# Docker: Publishing ports from a user-defined network to a specific host IP address with docker-java

Tags: java, docker, docker-network, docker-java

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

```
-p 192.168.1.100:8080:80
```

with docker-java. The only example that I found for publishing/mapping ports with docker-java is using the **.withExposedPorts** of the **CreateContainerCmd** class. [here](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/638b2ad033a281160c6545eb30f1b7d014505905/src/test/java/com/github/dockerjava/cmd/CreateContainerCmdIT.java#L499).

I'm not seeing any way of specifying a host IP address. I wonder if this is something supported from the docker-java project?

Comment: I want to expose them only for the localhost of the host machine - 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Then you can do something like [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/exposing-ports-only-to-localhost/20868/2). `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:80`

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem here. I want to achieve this via the docker-java project and its API. https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `Binding.bindIpAndPort` ?

https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/638b2ad033a281160c6545eb30f1b7d014505905/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/model/Ports.java#L145

Comment: Yes, this is what I found in the end of the day. Exactly what I needed!

I will propose an edit to your question so that we can make it more helpful for other people and then we can accept it. :)